# How to obtain the field type using dbfpy?

Tags: python, types, dbf

I have some dbf files that I want to add new fields to. To do so, I'm using [dbfpy](http://dbfpy.sourceforge.net/) to open the original dbf, copy all fields (or the ones I want to keep) and records and then create a new file with those fields plus the new ones that I want. All is working great, except for one minor detail: I can't manage to keep the original fields' types, since I don't know how to obtain them. What I'm doing is to create all the fields in the new file as "C" (character), which so far works for what I need right now but might be an issue eventually.

The real problem is that there is no documentation available. I searched through the package files to look for the examples there, but couldn't find an answer to this question (might be that I couldn't find just by the "greenish" I still am with python... I'm definitely not an expert).

An example of the code:

```
from dbfpy import dbf
import sys

org_db_file = str(sys.argv[1])
org_db = dbf.Dbf(org_db_file, new = False)

new_db_file = str(sys.argv[2])
new_db = dbf.Dbf(new_db_file, new = True)

#Obtain original field names:
fldnames = []
fldsize = {}
for names in org_db.fieldNames:
  fldnames.append(names)
  fldsize[name] = 0

#Cycle thru table entries:
for rec in org_db:

  #Cycle thru columns to obtain fields' name and value:
  for name in fldnames:
    value = str(rec[name])
    if len(value) > fldsize[name]:
      fldsize[name] = len(value)

#Copy original fields to new table:
for names in fldnames:
  new_db.addField((names, "C", fldsize[name]))

#Add new fields:
new_fieldname = "some_name"
new_db.addField((new_fieldname, "C", 2))

#Copy original entries and store new values:
for rec in org_db:

  #Create new record instance for new table:
  new_rec = new_db.newRecord()

  #Populate fields:
  for field in fldnames:
    new_rec[field] = rec[field]

  #Store value of new field for record i:
  new_rec[new_fieldname] = "some_value"
  new_rec.store()    

new_db.close()
```

Thanks in advance for your time.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with dbfpy other than when I first went looking several years ago it (and several others) did not meet my needs.  [So I wrote my own.](http://python.org/pypi/dbf)

Here is how you would accomplish your task using it:

```
import dbf
import sys

org_db_file = sys.argv[1]
org_db = dbf.Table(org_db_file)

new_db_file = sys.argv[2]
# postpone until we have the field names...
# new_db = dbf.Dbf(new_db_file, new = True)

# Obtain original field list:
fields = org_db.field_names
for field in fields[:]:  # cycle through a separate list
    if field == "something we don't like":
        fields.remove(field)

# now get definitions for fields we keep
field_defs = ord_db.structure(fields)

# Add new fields:
field_defs.append("some_name C(2)")

# now create new table
new_db = ord_db.new(new_db_file, field_specs=field_defs)

# open both tables
with dbf.Tables(ord_db, new_db):

    # Copy original entries and store new values:
    for rec in org_db:

        # Create new record instance for new table:
        new_db.append()

        # Populate fields:
        with new_db.last_record as new_rec:
            for field in new_db.field_names:
                new_rec[field] = rec[field]

                # Store value of new field for record i:
                new_rec[new_fieldname] = "some_value"
```